# Efficiently determining the number of pages in a large pdf using pdfbox 2.x

Tags: java, performance, pdf, pdfbox

Is there an efficient way to get the number of pages in a pdf using pdfbox 2.x?  Currently I execute the shell command pdfinfo from our java web app to get this information.  When I do the same thing with pdfbox, the code below gets me the correct number of pages, however it is much slower with large files than pdfinfo.  A 670 MB pdf file takes 270 ms in pdfinfo, and 7300 ms in pdfbox.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Date startDate = new Date();
    PDDocument document = null;
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\pdftest\\test.pdf")){
        MemoryUsageSetting memoryUsageSetting = MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(1024*1024*500);
        document = PDDocument.load(in, memoryUsageSetting);
        System.out.println(String.format("number of pages: %d", document.getNumberOfPages()));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if (document != null) {
            try {
                document.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("error closing the pdf file.");
            }
        }
    }

    Date endDate = new Date();

    System.out.println(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Your question is analog to this one: "Why does a Mercedes S500 consume more gas than a Nissan Micra when driving 200 metres to drop a letter into the postbox?"

Comment: PDFBox is designed for manipulation of the full file. When loading a PDF, it really is completely loaded. For most *info* purposes, though, you actually only need to load a small subset of the PDF objects. Thus, a specialized *info* tool automatically is faster than a generic library like PDFBox.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could write an Inputstream which loads the PDF and checks its content for the root page dictionary. If found, the `/Count` gives you the number of pages (since `/Count` is a required attribute). But please note that in later PDF specs the contents are flatencoded, so you need to flat decode first...

An example (PDF Spec 1.4):

```
...
30980 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 30881 0 R 
/Metadata 30868 0 R 
...
>> 
endobj
....
30881 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Pages 
/Kids [ ... ] 
/Count 978 
>>
```

Comment: thanks for the information, I will likely continue to use pdfinfo for the near future.  I don't want to get into parsing a raw pdf to look for the page count.

Comment: Yeah you were asking ;-)